# Bokeh CustomJS Piechart

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am trying to implement `js_on_change` on Pie graph but am unable to do so. I am new to `bokeh` and `JavaScript`. Below is my code. So basically I want to implement a functionality that whenever I deselect any fruit, then my Pie chart should redraw itself by excluding that fruit from the calculation.

My code is below.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,CustomJS,Slider
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum 

from bokeh.palettes import Category10
fruits = {'Apple': 10,
          'Mango': 24,
          'Graphes': 9,
          'Banana': 15,
          'Peach': 6,
          'Pinapple' : 7,
    }

data = pd.Series(fruits).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'Fruits'})
data['angle']=data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2 *pi
data['color'] = Category10[len(fruits)]
data['percent']= data['value']/sum(fruits.values()) *100
p=figure(plot_height= 350 , title='Pie chart',tools = "hover",
         tooltips="@Fruits: @value  : @percent{0.2f} %", x_range=(-0.5,1.0))
p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='Fruits', source=data)
p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color=None

callback =CustomJS(args = {'source':fruits},
code="""
var active=cb_obj.active;
const data = source;
const data1 = source;

var key1 = Object.keys(data)
var values1 = Object.values(data)
var new_fruit={}

var i=0
for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(data)) {
console.log(key,value);
console.log(active.includes(i));
var bool = active.includes(i);
if (bool==true)
  { console.log(active.includes(i));
    new_fruit[key]=value;

}
i=i+1
}


console.log("Callback completed");
console.log(active);
console.log(new_fruit);
"""
                  )
L = ["Apple","Mango","Graphes","Banana","Peach","Pinapple"]

checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=L, active =[0,1,2,3,4,5])
checkbox_group.js_on_change('active',callback)
layout = column(checkbox_group,p)

show(layout)
```

[This is the image of PieChart I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZMK7.png)

Comment: I am trying to do the same, I figure that you need to do the callback on the start and end angles though once you do it the cumsum model that you use to create the plot won't be there, so now I am trying to figure out how to add it to the callback.